# R- Trying to get time difference between each row (sequential location)?

Tags: r, dplyr, average

I have this [data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4H1sg.png) (It's not allowing me to show the picture here). I am trying to get the time difference between each sequential location grouped by component name. So basically, I want to see how long each component takes at a certain location and then want to get the average time for any component takes at a location and then by location and component type. I was originally trying to spread the data so that the location would be the key and the times the value and then get the difference between the columns but each component type has different locations so that did not work.

```
comps <- structure(list(component_name = c("COMPONENT000000001", 
    "COMPONENT000000001", 
"COMPONENT000000001", "COMPONENT000000001", "COMPONENT000000001", 
"COMPONENT000000001", "COMPONENT000000002", "COMPONENT000000002", 
"COMPONENT000000002", "COMPONENT000000002", "COMPONENT000000002", 
"COMPONENT000000002", "COMPONENT000000002"), component_type = 
    structure(c(4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("component_0", 
"component_1", "component_2", "component_3"), class = "factor"), 
    location = structure(c(6L, 2L, 14L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 14L, 
    14L, 1L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("29MSJ_03_01", "5YU1V_01_02", 
    "7EFLP_03_02", "assembly room", "B57X3_03_00", "GH9CV_00_03", 
    "HUX1L_02_02", "JX3UO_01_01", "MRX5B_01_00", "TG6IA_00_02", 
    "VUFVH_00_00", "YBSFJ_00_01", "ZAENM_02_01", "ZZU3X_02_00"
    ), class = "factor"), times = structure(c(1514764800, 1514771683, 
    1514784872, 1514794911, 1514806504, 1514820010, 1514764800, 
    1514776184, 1514789862, 1514794911, 1514806046, 1514831050, 
    1514843151), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "America/New_York")), .Names = c("component_name", 
"component_type", "location", "times"), row.names = c(NA, 13L
), class = "data.frame")



loc_diff <- comps %>%
          group_by(., type, location) %>%
          mutate(., diff = as.numeric(difftime(max(times), min(times))))
ld <- loc_diff %>%
      group_by(., location) %>%
      summarise(., avg = mean(diff))
```

This is was originally what I tried to do but then it gave me a dataframe with all the averages being about the same and I don't think that's right based off other exploration I have done. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

P.S. I'm not sure if I should be doing a tsa on this but I am new to that and I am still trying to get that to work.

Comment: Please `dput(comps)` and share output as part of question. It will be easier in that way.

Comment: @MKR is that how you meant?

Comment: Yes, Thanks. I can work on it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can first calculate the time spend on each location by a component by grouping on `component_name` and then taking difference between `times` of next row and current row. One can use `difftime` to find difference between two times (in say seconds).

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

#First get the time spend by each component at a location
comps_timesSpendAtLocatoin <- comps %>%
  group_by(component_name) %>%
  mutate(timeSpendAtLocation = difftime(lead(times),times, units = "secs"))

#Group_by 'component_name' to find average time spend on a location by each component
comps_timesSpendAtLocatoin %>% group_by(component_name) %>%
  summarise(avgTimeComponentAtLocation = mean(timeSpendAtLocation, na.rm = TRUE))
# component_name     avgTimeComponentAtLocation
# <chr>              <time>                    
# 1 COMPONENT000000001 11042                     
# 2 COMPONENT000000002 13058.5 

#Average time spend on a location by component_type and location  
comps_timesSpendAtLocatoin %>% group_by(component_type, location) %>%
  summarise(avgTimeComponentTypeAtLocation = mean(timeSpendAtLocation, na.rm = TRUE))

# # A tibble: 5 x 3
# # Groups: component_type [?]
# component_type location      avgTimeComponentTypeAtLocation
# <fctr>         <fctr>        <time>                        
# 1 component_3    29MSJ_03_01   15551                         
# 2 component_3    5YU1V_01_02   13433.5                       
# 3 component_3    assembly room NaN                           
# 4 component_3    GH9CV_00_03   9133.5                        
# 5 component_3    ZZU3X_02_00   8741
```